# ¿Por qué MySQL 8 tiene dos conexiones activas desde localhost?

Tags: mysql, localhost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al ejecutar show processlist en MySQL 8, me muestra 3  conexiones desde localhost. Quisiera saber por qué, si en teoría no tengo conectado ningún programa con PHP o algo similar a la base de datos.

Comment: `Daemon` es el servicio en ejecución. `Query` fue iniciado por el comando para mostrar los procesos y `Sleep` es la usada por el manejador de bases de datos: Workbench, PhpMyAdmin u otro.

Comment: La segunda conexión es del IDE, es decir, si usas `Workbench`, `PHPMyAdmin`, etc. te va a aparecer esa conexión. Si ejecutas el comando desde la consola, dicha conexión no deberia aparecer.

Comment: Realmente no tienes dos conexiones activas, porque [`show processlist`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) no muestra SOLAMENTE las conexiones activas, sino los procesos activos que son en tu caso: 1. El programador de eventos (está encendido y esperando a que se dispare algún evento); 2. La consulta que acabas de lanzar `show processlist;`; 3. Sleep, que indica que la consulta ha terminado y MySQL entró en estado de reposo, hasta que reciba una nueva orden ... o la conexión se cierre agotado un tiempo determinado.

Comment: @Triby pon eso como una respuestas porque es bastante segun veo

Answer (score 0):

No son 3 conexiones activas, de acuerdo [al enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) que te proporcionó @A.Cedano en comentarios:

> The MySQL process list indicates the operations currently being performed by the set of threads executing within the server. The SHOW PROCESSLIST statement is one source of process information.

En español sería algo como:

> La lista de procesos indica las operaciones que están siendo ejecutadas por el juego de hilos de ejecución en el servidor. La declaración `SHOW PROCESSLIST` es una fuente de información de procesos.

En resumen, se listan procesos y no conexiones. Según la imagen mostrada, los procesos están relacionados con:

1. `Daemon` es el servicio en ejecución y simplemente está en espera de una orden para ejecutar (status: Waiting for next activation)
2. `Query` es el proceso lanzado por la consulta realizada
3. `Sleep` es el proceso ejecutado por tu manejador de base de datos, que también está en espera de ejecutar un nuevo comando

Para saber el total de conexiones activas, accede a la [variable correspondiente](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections). Puedes ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE
    variable_name LIKE "Threads_%"
    OR variable_name = "Connections";
```

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502036/how-can-i-see-how-many-mysql-connections-are-open) (en inglés), se va a mostrar algo como:

```
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Connections       | 22742 |
| Threads_cached    | 1     |
| Threads_connected | 87    |
| Threads_created   | 549   |
| Threads_running   | 51    |
+-------------------+-------+
```

- Connections

  Cantidad total de intentos de conexión al servidor MySQL, exitosos o no.
- Threads_cached

  Cantidad de hilos en caché.
- Threads_connected

  Cantidad de conexiones actualmente abiertas.
- Threads_created

  Cantidad de hilos creados para manejar las conexiones. Si el número es muy grande, tal vez deberías incrementar el valor de la configuración para `trhead_cache_size_value`.
- Threads_running

  Total de hilos en ejecución que no están "dormidos" (en espera).